# Watir access Gmail

Tags: ruby, gmail, watir

I want to login to gmail but the code below does not send the email and password to the web page:

```
require 'gmail'    
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
$browser.goto "gmail.com"

gmail = Gmail.new("myaccount@gmail.com", "Password")
```

Comment: What gem are you using?

Comment: Please see here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89a928530731724fc91f89200b2c0939

Comment: Any errors or logs?

Comment: Nope it says test passed which is not true.

Comment: Does the Chrome version got anything to do with this? I'm using Chrome driver 2.34 and browser v63

Comment: I do not recommend using this. Not very stable.

Comment: I have down graded to v2.33 still does not work probably is not Chrome's problem.

Comment: I ran this from command line and I'm getting this error message: [6868:7632:0104/151025.398:ERROR: shader_disk_cache.cc<238>] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2

Comment: Looks like you are trying to login to the browser via the `gmail` gem.  You'll have to use `watir` if you want to login via the UI.

Comment: I did add require 'watir' but still getting the same error message when I run from command line.

Comment: I have not had luck with the gmail gem, either. I wrote an answer about my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052580/reading-a-gmail-message-with-ruby-gmail/27054372#27054372

Comment: But also as @orde mentioned, if you want to simply fill out the fields via the UI you would use Watir (only). The gem would not be needed for that purpose.